# Autocomplete jQuery not working on live server

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using jquery UI autocomplete for a search on my site. It's working properly without any problems while is on localhost. But on the live server it doesn't get any results. I have reviewed many posts on this topic, but I am still stymied as to why this doesn't work. I don't know if I can tell you the name of web hosting I use or not.

**HTML code: index.php**

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="" name="ser" class="form-control" id="hotels" value="" required />
```

**javascript code**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $( "#hotels" ).autocomplete({
        source: 'scripts/chresults.php'
    });
});
 </script>
```

**chresults.php**

```html
<?php
$dbHost = '';
$dbUsername = '';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbName = '';
//connect with the database
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
//get search term
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
//get matched data from skills table

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE hotel LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' or hotelen LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'  or city LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'limit 5") or die ('mysql_error');
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) 
 {
    $results['city'] = $row['city'];
 $results[] = $row['hotel'].' , '.$row['city'];
 }
//return json data
$json_string = json_encode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $json_string;

?>
```

Comment: It isn't a case you've got no data in you table? If not are you getting javascript errors?

Comment: Check your network tab in browser (F12), press refresh on the problem page and see that all requests are 200 Ok. If one of them is 400 or 404 - there is the problem.

Comment: I've checked the console and I didn't find any errors

Comment: You'll need to see what is being sent and returned - using chrome  (press f12 for developer tools , click on network , then check on the XHR button)

Comment: Maybe it could be Cross-Origin problem where you receive only a warning after few minutes, Add in your PHP code `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Comment: mihkov has a very good point

Comment: In which file specifically can I add this code? chresults.php? @mihkov

Comment: Thank you both. You were right @mihkov

Comment: Glad to help. It is common error in communication between servers, But I suggest you to replace `*` with your IP or domain. Currently it allows all.